# How to set domain for curency_id field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have an entity with 2 fields payment (manetary) and its currency. The currency_id field in the view displays a list of all possible currencies. How can I set domain to the curency_id field so the user only will be able to select two possible currencies? In this case the options would be: US Dollar (USD) and Dominican Peso (DOP)

`payment  = fields.Monetary(string='Payment',currency_field='currency_id')
currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', string='Currency', required=True)`

And in the view:
`<field name="payment"/>

<field name="currency_id"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add domain on `currency_id` field. `Name` field available on `res.currency` object to find desire currency.

Try with following code:

```
currency_id = fields.Many2one(
    'res.currency', 
    string='Currency', 
    required=True, 
    domain=[('name', 'in', ('USD', 'DOP'))])
```

Comment: That work, but the selection widget is not showing DOP cause that currency is not active by default. How can I activate DOP when installing the module. I have try with this but that code is for adding a new currency, and what I want to do is to set the field 'active' of an existing currency as True. What should I do to modify that record? 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
`<odoo>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <record id="74" model="res.currency">
      <field name="active">True</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>`

Comment: @tico1993 You can active it from `Currencies` menu. Not from XML id. `Currencies` menu will be locate different based on Odoo version. You can reference Accounting > Configuration or Sales > Configuration. Fine `DOP` currency record and active it.

Comment: Those modules are not installed, nor I need Them for my application